# Совместимость устройств iOS в AppStore

Tags: ios, appstore

Сегодня опубликовали мое приложение в AppStore
Совместимость начинается от iPhone 5S и iPad Air (iOS8)

Подскажите каким образом я могу снизить планку совместимости устройств, от iPhone 4 и iPad 2?

На сколько нашел информации что надо прописать в plist чтото...
Там стоит armv7

Comment: Это делается в xcode. Выбираешь просто iOS. Тебе нужен iOS6

Comment: У меня используются методы, которые требуют iOS8. Отладку делать на iPhone 4S могу... Может есть еще варианты как расширить список?

Comment: а как вы определили, что iPhone5s и iPad Air? iOS8 поддерживается и более старыми устройствами. Например iPhone4s поддерживает iOS9.

Comment: Ну во-первых не дает поставить поставить программу из AppStore на 4S... Во-вторых список поддерживаемых устройств написан к каждой программе выложенной в AppStore. В моем случае все что новее 5S

Comment: я слепой, нигде такого не вижу. где такое посмотреть?

Comment: В браузере под иконкой приложения есть поле Совместимость: Требуется iOS 7.0 или более поздняя версия. Совместимо с iPhone, iPad и iPod touch.

Comment: В моем случае там перечисление устройств от iphone5s

Comment: мистика. никогда такого не видел, чтоб какие то конкретные девайсы там были. а какие архитектуры поддерживает приложение?

Comment: Я довольно часто встречал подобное. В plist указано armv7

Comment: а в build settings `Architectures` и `Valid Architectures`?

Comment: Standart arm64 armv7 armv7s

Comment: ну тогда последняя попытка: что у вас в `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` в plist?

Comment: и еще, используется ли в приложении openGL или Metal?

Comment: Там пусто, это значение не добавлял. По графике ничего нет. Склоняюсь к варианту @mix о том что надо цель ставить iOS6 или 7. Но придется переписывать часть кода....